# Update mysql from PHP working only on second try

Tags: php, forms, file, upload

I am stuck, I cannot figure out what is going on. I hit the Browse button and select a CSV file, I Click to upload the file and get the failed message "Invalid File type". I hit the browse button again and select the same file and it works the second time around.
Can someone tell me where is the problem?

```
<?php
//ini_set('display_errors',1);
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myuser";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydb";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}   

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
     //echo 'upload file name: '.$fname.' ';
     $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

     if(strtolower(end($chk_ext)) == "csv")
     {

         $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
         $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
         mysqli_query($conn, 'TRUNCATE TABLE custstatements;');
         while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
         {
            if ($data[2] != 'Customer No' and $data[2] >''){
                $sql = "INSERT into custstatements(custNum, field1, field2, invNum, custPo, refNum, amount, payment, balance) values('$data[2]','$data[5]','$data[7]','$data[6]','$data[9]','$data[10]','$data[12]','$data[13]','$data[14]')";
                if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                    echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
                }   
            }

         }
        mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE custstatements SET invoiceDate = STR_TO_DATE(field1, '%m/%d/%Y'), invDueDate = STR_TO_DATE(field2, '%m/%d/%Y') ");
        mysqli_close($conn);
        header('Location: index.php');          
     }
     else
     {
       echo "Invalid File type only a CSV file can be imported.";
     }  
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Statement Data Upload</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<a href="index.php" title="Home"><img src="images/logo-deville.svg"></a>
<div class="headder"><h1>STATEMENTS DATA UPLOAD</h1><hr>
</div>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select CSV file to upload:
<input type="file" name="sel_file">
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Ravi. It turns out that my home page was calling a bad page called fileupload.php which in turn had a form with action=upload.php and the latest is the page containing my code above which worked. I can't believe how much time I spend before figuring out this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your file checker to:

```
$checker=  array('csv');
$fileToUpload= $_FILES['self_file']['name'];
$myFile= pathinfo($fileToUpload, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(in_array($myFile,$checker) ) {
   // upload here
}
```